# Run the function once and get the return and use in a loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I have problems to get the return of a model and use in a loop (foreach) without the function to be ran again many times ...
How can I do to get the return and use this same return several times?
Code for illustration:

```
$valueModel = $this->model->function(); // get return


foreach ($var as $var2) {
    $array = array(
        'Db' => $var2->item,
        'Db' => $valueModel, // run function many times
        'Db' => $var2->item
    );
        }
```

Comment: You are probably overwritting the value because you use 3 identical index namings "Db", so you Will only get the last. Try unique indexes for all 3.

Comment: The var `$array` will also get overwritten each time `foreach` loops. So if you intend to use `$array` after the loop there will be only one item in the array.

Comment: Also, `$var2->item` is dedicated twice.

Answer (score 0):

the correct way to do that is like

```
$var        = $this->model->function(); // get return @return array
$valueModel = $this->model->function(); // get row @return strig

$data_array = array();

$i = 0;
foreach($var as $row){
    $data_array[$i] = array(
                            'Db1' => $row->item,
                            'Db2' => $valueModel, // run function many times
                            'Db3' => $row->item //check if this is the correct value
                          );

    $i++;
}

var_dump($data_array);
```